# Django Rest Framework how to get response from server via request

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have my clients server at brilalls.cruxomux.com

Now my client has some JSON APIs already ready with his application which is working fine.

Now he wants me to connect with his APIs and get the response from his server. I have gone through the Django Rest Framework, but I am clueless on how to implement the following situation:

1. My client has the API called `brilalls.cruxomux.com/api/bookmark/add` which adds bookmark to his mysql backend. Idon''t know what's haappening in backend. Also for example: he has `brilalls.cruxomux.com/api/bookmark/delete` and `brilalls.cruxomux.com/api/bookmark/get` each api has its own work.
2. Now I have my this Django runserver installed in my local machine.

He asks me to do **Request** like this:

```
Request
{
    session : 9872152t4fhf390t34y2t83refchslmsag0vu5t2
    bookmark_id:12
}
```

And says that the **Response** will be this:

```
Success Response
{
    action:"add_bookmark"
    success:"true"
}
```

And if it fails it will give us a **Failed  Response** like this:

```
Failed Response
{
    success : false
    action:"add_bookmark"
    error : {"message" : "Error in processing"}
}
```

Now my issue is I am clueless on how exactly I can achieve this via **Django Rest Framework** or how exactly I can utilize DRF for my purpose as my client is sure that this can be done using DRF. Kindly help.

Comment: Why do you need to use django rest framework? This can be done by using a tool like [`httpie`](http://httpie.org) or a library like [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org). DRF is for _creating_ a webservice, not necessarily to consume one.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I don't know he wanted it to be in DRF, However what will be better, actually I am new to this RESTful concept... I have also heard about urllib2... What you suggest what I should do in this case? Is it possible through DRF or I should go with any other lib?

Comment: @DjangoAnonymous you didn't pay attention to what Burhan said. It simply doesn't make sense to ask if you can use DRF for this: that is just not what it is for. It's like asking if you can use Django to bake brownies with. Actually, you probably misunderstood what your client said: you should use the [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thanks guys, a direct answer. Got it :)